# Insert tasks at agenda/calendar view

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, calendar, todo

I am thinking about mimicking Outlook interface on this.

Let say I am planning my week, and I see that on Tuesday next week I don't see any todo there. So, I move the cursor to the date and hit some keyboard shortcut. Then I will be able to add a todo task to the date. The task will be saved in a preconfigured file (i.e. todo.org). How do I do this?

In `calendar` view I can see that I can add a diary entry to date. But I need more customization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For agenda view, I found out `Capture with cursor date` <kbd>k</kbd> does what I want after setting `(setq org-default-notes-file "~/todo.org")` in my `.emacs`.

It is not that visual compared to Outlook calendar, but good enough for me.

Comment: For calendar views, there is the built-in 3-month view that can be configured to colorize birthdays, holidays, tasks, events, etc.  For a fancy calendar that outdoes anything that I've ever seen for Emacs, check out the CFW library:  https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw  There is also a 12-month rotating view http://stackoverflow.com/a/21409154/2112489

Comment: @lawlist Calfw is indeed stunning. Now the only thing missing is  the functionality to add appointment in Calfw view.

Comment: The CWF library handles appointments and holidays out of the box -- it scans the `org-agenda-files` using the `org-agenda-entry-types`  -- i.e., there is a variable used by CFW that uses those values.  You will need to setup up `org-capture` templates to create entries in the org-files so that they show up on the calendar.  You can also create a simple function to create a pop-up template for the current date that adds the entry to the calendar.  I fixed a few bugs, but I do not know if the author will implement my suggestions -- have a look at Github issue number 61.

Comment: Any idea how to do this at _CALENDAR_ (not agenda). Similar to 'k' in Agenda?